# How to fix "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'useSystemColorMode')"

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, chakra-ui

So I am using ChakraUI and React JS to make a project. Whenever I start the project it gives me the error, "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'useSystemColorMode')". 
I didn't edit any global theme or anything in chakra. I just started making the navbar, designed with CSS. And when I try to run it, it shows me the error.
here is my navbar component

```
import React from "react";
import { MenuItems } from "./MenuItems";
import "./navbar.css";

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <>
      <nav className='NavbarItems'>
        <h1 className='navbar-logo'></h1>
        <div className='menu-icon'></div>
        <ul>
          {MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={index}>
                <a className={item.cname} href={item.url}>
                  {item.title}
                </a>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Navbar CSS file

```
.NavbarItems {
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

App.js file

```
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/provider";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar";
function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Navbar />
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Provided code doesn't reflect the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically this is a problem with ChakraUI theme,even though I did not do anything with ChakraUI theme or whatsoever.
I added theme.js file which included the following:

```
// theme.js

// 1. import `extendTheme` function
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";

// 2. Add your color mode config
const config = {
  initialColorMode: "light",
  useSystemColorMode: true,
};

// 3. extend the theme
const theme = extendTheme({ config });

export default theme;
```

then I included the following in index.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { ColorModeScript } from "@chakra-ui/color-mode";
import theme from "./theme";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ColorModeScript initialColorMode={theme.config.initialColorMode} />
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And it worked. If anyone facing the same problem, you can check out https://chakra-ui.com/docs/features/color-mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Did exactly what you said and it saved me a big fat headache :-)

Answer (score 0):

Once I used extendTheme instead of an object for theme the error was gone. https://chakra-ui.com/docs/theming/customize-theme

Comment: check my comment, which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to check the name of the message type (error, success, warning)
if you misspell it, the error will occure

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).